# C#: Three build errors that I can't figure out

Tags: c#

I am getting three errors that are preventing my program from running and I cant figure out what they mean? I must be stupid because I even have my C# book next to me and it still doesn't make sense. Any help would be great. The errors are:

1. Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\obj\x86\Release\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main()'. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.
2. 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override
3. Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\obj\x86\Release\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'Text.Main()'. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

Code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 public class Text : Form
 {

private Font arialBold24 = new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold);

private Font timesItalic14 = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Italic);

private Font courierPlain18 = new Font("Courier New", 18, FontStyle.Strikeout);

private Font genericSerifBI20 = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 20, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);

private Font verdanaPlain18 = new Font("Verdana", 18, FontStyle.Regular | FontStyle.Underline);


public Text()
{

    Size = new Size(400, 200);

    Text = "Text";

    BackColor = Color.White;

}



protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    int w = (int)g.MeasureString(arialBold24.Name, arialBold24).Width;

    int arialStart = (Width - w) / 2;

    int otherStart = Width / 4;

    int h = DisplayRectangle.Height;

    g.DrawString(arialBold24.Name, arialBold24, Brushes.Blue, arialStart, 0);

    g.DrawString(timesItalic14.Name, timesItalic14, Brushes.Blue, otherStart, h / 5);

    g.DrawString(courierPlain18.Name, courierPlain18, Brushes.Blue, otherStart, 2 * h / 5);

    g.DrawString(genericSerifBI20.Name, genericSerifBI20, Brushes.Blue, otherStart, 3 * h / 5);

    g.DrawString(verdanaPlain18.Name, verdanaPlain18, Brushes.Blue, otherStart, 4 * h / 5);

    base.OnPaint(e);

}

public static void Main()
{

    Application.Run(new Text());

}

}
```

The program.cs code is:

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
 static class Program
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
 }
 }
```

Updated Code of Form1:

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Program.CS code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Text());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Based on the errors, it looks like you have some other code in your project - a Form1.cs and a Program.cs. Can you post those, too? You can probably delete those or exclude them from your project to solve the errors.

Comment: Look in your project, you probably have a `Program.cs` file, which already defines the main method (the one you put at the end of the above code). You can delete the main method in your form class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need another `Main` method in class `Text`, as it is already defined in the `Program.cs` file if you use the built-in template to create a WinForms app.

I hope removing the redundant `Main` method from class `Text` may be enough to run the app successfully.

---

### EDIT

In the `Program.cs` file, instantiate the `Text` class instead of `Form1` like below:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Text());
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to enclose the class `Text` with the following namespace:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Text : Form
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT 2:

Please override the `Dispose()` method inside class `Form1` like below:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: now I am getting the  error:                                                                 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: no, you have posted the code of class `Text` again. Pls post class `Form1`.

Comment: Its okay. I am not worthy of that. Our Almighty Creator is the only lifesaver. btw, good luck!